# Regex: largst repeating match

Tags: regex

I want to process the string like :

```
"M234hhg M lskdjf M sjkdfjs M lksjdf M",
```

And I wrote a Regular expressions : `"[\s]?M([^Z])+?M"`

the match result is：

```
M234hhg M

M sjkdfjs M
```

I want to get the result like ：

```
M234hhg M

M LSKDJF M

M sjkdfjs M

M LKSJDF M
```

How would regular expression for above string set look like?

Comment: Are you looking something like this? [\s]?M([A-Za-z])+?M

Comment: I think you should split the string at the letter "M", and manually reconstruct the `M`string`M` form for the items...

Comment: Regex can't do this, because matches *consume* the input - you can't "reuse" the `M` as both the end and the start of each matching token.